# Foreign Object returns null (Entity framework .net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to get the employee's department names via the virtual department object but it returns null.

Here is my employee class.
I declared the department as a virtual value.
Employee.cs

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } = "EMP";
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my Department class.
Department.cs

```
public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the Context Class
Context.cs

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = null;
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; } = null;


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().ToTable("Department");
        }

        public TestContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }


    }
```

IndexModel.cs

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly TestContext _context;

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public List<Employee> Emps { get; set; }

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, TestContext context)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
                try
                {
                    Emps = _context.Employees.ToList();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Emps = new List<Employee>();
                }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add the model data declaration to the post, please. Show how you prepare the view data on the controller side, before render the view.

Comment: @Victor please check my question now

Comment: Add an `.Include()` - like this: ` Emps = _context.Employees.Include(e => e.Department).ToList();` to also load the `Department` for each employee

Comment: @ManarAl-Zabadani: See the following article: [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)